# Doubt regarding vacuous statement in Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I came across this vacuous statement that : empty set is clopen because it's both open and closed vacuously. As $\mathrm{int}\,\emptyset=\emptyset$ and $ \emptyset'=\emptyset$ this means that both the interior set and the set of limit points of empty set is empty, and using vacuous logic it has nothing to contain as there's nothing to begin with so the empty set contains all it's interior and limit points. So clopen.

Now i know that a set is closed if it contains all it's limit points i.e $E' \subset E$, and open if it contains all of it's interior points. Now considering the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ it's easy to see tht $\mathbb{Z}$ has no limit points so $\mathbb{Z}'=\emptyset$, and vacuously it contains all of it's limit points so it's closed. But also $\mathrm{int}\,\mathbb{Z}=\emptyset$, so it should contain all of it's interior point (vacuously), which implies $\mathbb{Z}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, which is not correct from the complementary arguments.

I don't know where i'm going wrong? is it the definition of open or closed sets or the vacuous statement ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong here:

> and open if it contains all of it's interior points

Symbolically you wrote $int(U)\subseteq U$ which is always true for any subset, open or not. It's the other way around: a subset is open if its every point is an interior point, i.e. $U\subseteq int(U)$.

That's why $\mathbb{Z}$ is not open: none of its points is an interior point, since the interior is empty as you've correctly noted.

And so this is unrelated to vacuous truth, you've just got the description of open subsets mixed up.

Comment: A set is open if all of its points are interior points, **NOT** "if it contains all of its interior points"!  Every set "contains all of its interior points" by definition of "interior point".

Comment: Ah, got it; thanks @freakish and user247327.

Comment: Just to clarify : so $\mathbb{Z}$ actually contains all of it's interior points right? But that doesn't make it open as none of the points on $\mathbb{Z}$ is an interior point of $\mathbb{Z}$, as around each point in $\mathbb{Z}$ if we consider some neighborhood there will always exist some points that are not in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @user440024 yes, exactly. It just happens that $int(\mathbb{Z})=\emptyset$.